# How will the compression ratio increase thermal effeciency of otto cycle while Win is higher?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle, combustion

Why the ideal otto cycle thermal effeciency increase with compression ratio although that will increase work input? While the temperature difference in the combustion chamber could be low,the overall effect is decrease in nth otto. Regardless of the compression ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason that efficiency increases with compression ratio is it raises the temperature at which the heat is added to the working fluid. The work input is recovered during the expansion phase of the cycle- it is not lost.